# Webpart call to Web Handler

Tags: c#, sharepoint, web-parts, ashx

I have a webpart which calls ASP.NET handler to accomplish the autocomplete functionality.

```
ASHX File
    <%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="MyService.MyAutoComplete" CodeBehind="MyAutoComplete.ashx.cs" %>
```

Code Behind File

```
namespace MyService
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for MyAutoComplete
    /// </summary>
    public class MyAutoComplete : IHttpHandler
    {
        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            var searchTerm = context.Request.QueryString["term"].ToString();

            context.Response.Clear();
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";


            var search = GetList();

            JavaScriptSerializer jsSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            string json = jsSerializer.Serialize(search);
            context.Response.Write(json);
            context.Response.End();
        }

    }
}
```

This is my JQuery call

```
$(function () {
            $("#<%= txtSearchInput.ClientID %>").autocomplete({
                source: "/_Layouts/My Service/MyAutoComplete.ashx",
                minLength: 2,
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    $(this).val(ui.item.value);
                }
            });
        });
```

The "My Service" is SharePoint layout folder inside the webpart project.

When I make call thro JQuery it throws the following error
"Could not create type 'MyService.MyAutoComplete'"

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Are you adding a reference to that dll file?If not add and rebuild application.

Comment: @coder the handler is part of the webpart project. So I don't think we need any reference.

Comment: Also I think you can have a small issue with calling your handler. You give a relative url "/_Layouts/My Service/MyAutoComplete.ashx" to jQuery autocomplete, that's why it will call it under root web of site collection, and so you can have some problems with permissions, lists querying, etc. Of course I can't claim it definitely, maybe it's a part of your design. But look into SharePoint js api SP.Utilities.Utility.getLayoutsPageUrl([yourHandlerUrl])
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee659418.aspx
It will generate url according to current web in site collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It Seems SharePoint components have its own way of identifying the components :). After googling I found the following solution.

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#"  Class="MyService.MyAutoComplete,MyProject, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=87c41094797c589e" %>
```

Answer (score 1):

When implementing [IHttpHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttphandler.aspx), you must provide an implementation for:

- The [ProcessRequest()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttphandler.processrequest.aspx) method (which you do),
- The [IsReusable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttphandler.isreusable.aspx) property (which you don't).

Therefore, the `MyAutoComplete` class cannot be instantiated, because it does not provide an implementation for all of `IHttpHandler`'s abstract members.

Since your handler is apparently stateless, you can implement `IsReusable` as follows:

```
public bool IsReusable
{
   get {
       // Handler is stateless, we can reuse the same instance
       // for multiple requests.
       return true;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I didn't include the IsReusable interface just to save some space here. If we don't implement the interface then the code doesn't even compile, you get compile time error.